# Заголовок таблицы при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Работаю с таблицей.
 Хочу чтобы строка с заголовками при прокрутке страницы спускался и пользователь при работе с таблицей всегда видел заголовки столбцов. Пробовала реализовать это с помощью `position: fixed;` и `position: relative;`.
Проблема в том, что заголовочная строка отделяется от основной таблицы и столбцы с данными сужаются до размеров текста в них (не ориентируясь на th). Хочу сделать что-бы эта строка всегда была на месте, но при прокрутке скрола как-то копировалась, что-ли, и была вверху той части таблицы, на которой находится пользователь.
 Подскажите, какими методами можно реализовать подобное? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 } 
 
 
table td:nth-child(1), 
table th:nth-child(1) { min-width: 150px; text-align: left }
 
table td:nth-child(2),
table th:nth-child(2) { min-width: 150px; text-align: left}
 
table td:nth-child(3),
table th:nth-child(3) { min-width: 100px; text-align: left}

table td:nth-child(4),
table th:nth-child(4) { width: 100px; text-align: left}

table  thead {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FDFDFD;   
  }
  
table thead tr {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
}

table tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;   
}

table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
        <th>Заголовок2</th>
        <th>Заголовок3</th>
        <th>Заголовок4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>defghijklmnopqrs</td>
        <td>tuv</td>
        <td>wxyz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чисто стилями - только если согласиться с тем, что ширины ячеек придется задавать явно.

С яваскриптом - навесить на событие прокрутки таблицы функцию, которая применит к `<thead>` или `<thead><tr>` css-сдвиг `transform:translateY(N)`, где N - число пикселей, на которые прокручена таблица относительно исходного положения.